Is my key in the car?
Recently we could not find one of the car keys. It was after coming home so almost certainly the key is in the car or in the house, however I wonder if I can narrow down the search a lot:
At the moment the car does not auto lock when walking away. I am starting to doubt myself but am pretty sure it always did this within a few minutes and now even if I come back after two hours while leaving the other key in the house I can just open the door.
In the past I believe this only happened when the key was in the car.
I did try starting the car but then it says the key is not detected. In the past this also happened if the key was on the back seat, but I guess I wonder now:

Does my car likely have auto lock
Does the auto lock use the same key detector as the starting system?

The car is a Mercedes c180 Estate from 2017. I can provide more details if needed.

I tried looking it up, and found inconsistent answers about having an auto lock and would not even know how to approach the second question.

Did you try searching online for M-B owner's manuals for your model and year? There may be M-B online forums too. Owner's manual and car forums with similar models often share valuable info like how your remote operates. And, of course, M-B dealers.
